# Try to use zipstatic but got no response

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to use [Zipstatic](http://daspecster.github.io/ziptastic/demo.html) with jQuery. My code is like below. But I don't get any response. Do I miss something?

```
jQuery(function() {

  jQuery("#form").hide();
  jQuery("#postcode").keyup(function() {

    var country = jQuery("#country");
    var postcode = jQuery(this);

      jQuery.ajax({
        url: "http://zip.elevenbasetwo.com/v2/" + country.val() + "/" + postcode.val(),
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",
        success: function(result, success) {
          jQuery("#city").val(result.city);
          jQuery("#state").val(result.state);
          jQuery("#form").slideDown();
          jQuery("#postcode").blur();
          jQuery("#country").blur();
          jQuery("#address1").show().focus();

        },
        error: function(result, success) {
          jQuery(".zip-error").slideDown(300);
        }
      });
  });
});
```

If I simply enter http://zip.elevenbasetwo.com/v2/US/48867 from my browser, then I got response. I just need to enter 2 variables, country and postcode into the url to get response. But why it doesn't work?

Comment: Are `#country` and `#postcode` input tags?

Comment: #country is select tag, #postcode is input tag.

Comment: What's the value of `url` at the moment of sending? (check with console.log()) and why use `jQuery` word instead of `$`?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this in Google Chrome console and it runs well.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "http://zip.elevenbasetwo.com/v2/US/48867",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    type: "GET",
    success: function(result, success) {
     console.log(result);

    },
    error: function(result, success) {
      jQuery(".zip-error").slideDown(300);
    }
  });
```

with no errors.
Maybe you're not sendind the right params to URL call. Do you have you HTML?

Comment: Thanks, HTML form just normal, with all are input tags, only #country is select tag. Did I write the url parameter correctly?